# 'Elementary' particles (electrons) vs non-elementary particles (protons) regarding relativistic mass

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy, quarks, elementary-particles

Is there a possible slight difference between protons and electrons behaviour while they are accelerated at speeds that cause relativistic changes to their mass. Why am I asking that? Because for a proton we know that it is made of several components which of them are the three quarks. If they have some speed inside the proton it is logical that this is not the same as they have no any intrinsic speed and that this speed does not matter as a portion that is added to the overall speed of the proton that is accelerated to a relativistic speed. Should that small part of the overall speed make a difference between the theoretical calculation of the particle speed to relativistic mass ratio and the empyrical results as the theoretical calculation threats the proton as an elementary particle because the intrinsic speeds of proton components are neglected in the formula?

Comment: No. Any system has to obey Einstein's energy momentum relation. And you should not use the concept of relativistic mass in the first place. It is a continuing source of confusion.

Comment: In terms of an intuitive understanding of "mass" you might find reading up on "effective mass" of electrons in solids somewhat enlightening. At least it helps me to "grok" how a non-zero mass of electrons is created by the background of the Higgs field to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything inside the proton transforms in the same way as an electron would, including intra-quark binding energies and such, so no, the observed energy ("relativistic mass") of composite particles is obtained in the same way as the energy of elementary particles. This is backed up by experiment too, literally billions of particles have been processed in particle accelerators and no deviation from Lorentz invariance has been observed.